# Is it possible to make webpack's watch mode work on Windows?

Tags: windows, webpack, watch, fsevents

I'm trying to enable webpack's watch mode on my Windows environment, however it only works with pooling enabled which makes my machine very slow and almost impracticable to work with.

Command used:

```
webpack --watch --progress
```

From webpack's official webservice there are two ways to check for file changes, polled and non-polled.
It can be changed by setting on the webpack configuration file. (see https://webpack.js.org/configuration/watch/)

Polling mode works by checking "manually" for changes every N seconds and on large projects this results in high CPU usage and a very slow environment.

Non-polled mode is the best and faster option since it waits on events from the operating system, however the watcher uses **fsevents** which is not available in Windows.

Everything works fine using MacOS.

Is there are way to make watch mode correctly on Windows in non-polled mode, using OS file change events?